# am I doing something wrong re: Rails with_lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locking

For Rails versions from 4.2 through 5.1.7 the code below worked fine.

In Rails 5.2, in my Rspec tests, unless I add an extra `reload` (shown below as a comment), it fails with the exception:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
  Locking a record with unpersisted changes is not supported. 
  Use `save` to persist the changes, or `reload` to discard them explicitly.
```

Since the call immediately before the with_lock is a `save` (as per the exception message) why would this still trigger an exception unless an extra `reload` is added right after the `save`?

```
  # merge into the serialized hash field 'settings' a new hash
  def update_settings(hash)
    return if hash.class != Hash
    return if !hash || (hash.count == 0)

    self.save # flush any pending changes
    # self.reload # <<<<< WHY MUST THIS BE added for rails 5.2?
    self.with_lock do
      mysettings = self.reload.settings
      # mysettings = self.settings
      hash.each do |k, v|
        mysettings[k] = v
      end
      self.update_attribute :settings, mysettings
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is `self.save` is failing. You should print `puts self.errors.full_messages` after your call to `self.save` to see why. Or you could replace `save` with `save!`.

Comment: superb idea, i will try that

Comment: yes, thanks, change it to save! then watched the exceptions in rspec and did indeed find a long-standing bug with an attribute that had a validation failure.